# Why, with such insanely powerful computers, are no efforts to speak of spent on security?

Tags: software, trust, third-party

The only technology "news" I ever hear about go on about "performance this" and "performance that". I haven't felt that my computer was "slow" since the 1990s. 20 years ago. Yet this is the only thing I ever hear anyone talk about.

Why, for example, do I have to run all these Composer PHP libraries with 100% privileges and total control of my PC? Why isn't there a simple way to tell PHP (in the config file, for example) that "this dir tree consists of third-party PHP scripts and is not to be trusted"?

I want to give these third-party scripts the most minimal series of privileges, for example:

1. You cannot see any dir outside of this list of dirs.
2. You cannot execute any terminal commands.
3. You cannot access these dangerous functions.
4. You cannot access the network in any way.

I've tried to bring this up numerous times to PHP developers and others, but it's like talking to a wall. They just mumble something about Docker and then stop responding.

Here's the thing: I don't know what kind of geniuses everyone is, or how stupid I am, but I've been utterly unable to figure out how to use Docker, so many times and with such a genuine effort, that I have given entirely up on the idea. Docker is not the solution. Docker is not what I want. Please don't suggest Docker.

I'm not even asking for a solution anymore -- I just wish to know why seemingly nobody cares one bit about even the most jarring security issues, which could relatively easily be fixed (compared to all the other things they do all the time).

I am simply *forced* to use various third-party libraries for complex operations. I'm also forced to trust them 100% instead of trusting them only "in their black box".

Please don't tell me that it's "easy" to set up this or that "security layer". It isn't easy. Trust me!

Why does nobody seem to care about security?

Comment: This is not a question, it is a rant in disguise. Furthermore, all the controls you mentioned above already exist. So the problem isn't the computer, it's you for not knowing how to secure it.

Comment: I think Docker pretty cleanly satisfies your requirements.

Comment: I think there's a genuine question in here somewhere, but I'm not sure where it is.  It's hard to start a question with a false premise that "nobody cares about security", which since this forum exists obviously isn't true.  What's true is that not everyone cares about security.  I don't think anyone can answer why some php developers don't care about security, since that's just not specific enough.

Comment: I didn't want to mention this in an answer, but I am currently prototyping a system to solve the PHP library problem you mention. It's based on static analysis rather than sandboxing, but has the same effect. Currently just looking at Java but the approach should work with other languages, including PHP.

Comment: @gowenfawr - Docker doesn't really solve the library problem. It can protect developer workstations, but you need to run your PHP app and all libraries in the same Docker, so a malicious library can still cause plenty of damage.

Comment: You've made quite a leap in logic to focus on "insanely powerful computers" to "I can't figure out how to segment PHP libraries" to "Why does nobody seem to care about security". That's what makes this a rant. If you would like to edit your question to talk about PHP, then we can re-open and provide answers. Right now, it's not answerable.

Answer (score 5):

Just before I answer your question, I'd like to point out some positives:

- Many tech vendors have greatly improved their security. For example, Microsoft was terrible for security back in 2000, but since the Trustworthy Computing email they have made great improvements.
- The Cyber Security industry has made significant steps to professionalise in a meaningful way with industry bodies like CREST. (previous efforts like ISC2 had significant flaws).
- There's a vibrant information sharing community both online and at local groups and conferences, although this tends to be focused on the offensive side.
- Key security components like TLS have improved greatly. Web browsers have been hardened with sandboxing and deprecating dangerous legacy like Flash and Java Applets.
- Web frameworks, and to a lesser extend programming languages, have improved significantly, with more security baked in and less left to app developers.
- Mobile operating systems have a better security design than older desktop operating systems, especially with applications being sandboxed. Unfortunately, they still have plenty of flaws.
- Many more high quality security products are available - code analyzers, fuzzers, sandboxing with virtualization, etc.
- Many countries or trans-national organisations have introduced strong cyber security legislation, such as GDPR in the EU. Unfortunately, these doesn't seem to have helped as much as hoped.
- In some environments you can have really strong security. I've seen this when doing pen tests of high value systems. It needs a combination of spending big and being prepared to inconvenience users and restrict functionality. If you've not had experience of such environments, you may think everywhere is as bad as typical consumer IT, but that's not the case.

However, there are some real difficulties:

- Compatibility is a massive concern. It really isn't an option to just break compatibility. This leaves us stuck with all sorts of things that were designed before security was such a concern and that it's hard to move away from.
- Computers are incredibly complicated, there is just so much going on within any modern device. It's impossible for one person to understand it all, and all sorts of unexpected interactions can introduce security flaws.
- There's an inherent imbalance in that an attacker only needs to find one way in, while a defender needs to protect every possible attack path.
- Often computerised systems replace legacy systems that had almost no security. For example, Companies House in the UK had very little verification of their paper-based processes. When they went online that made it easier to attack, so they've had to introduce new measures. However individual companies have to opt-in, essentially for backwards compatibility.

As to why no-one seems to care, there are a few reasons:

- Security is invisible - you only notice it when you have a breach. This manifests in a few ways:

  - Many Internet of Things devices have major security flaws, although some are well engineered. The thing is, most consumers will just buy the cheapest product that meets their visible requirements, so the cheap crap dominates the market.
  - With start up companies, there's a lot of pressure to build fast. If you take too much care of all the details, a competitor will overtake you. This leads to cutting corners, and invisible things like security are what tends to suffer.
- It's hard to assess the security of things. Even when experts do a detailed review of a system, it's quite common that further issues are found in future. This is not incompetence, it's just hard to do. Even really good security guys with the best tools can't guarantee complete coverage.

  - Because security is hard to assess, you can't really introduce government-mandated security standards (in a similar way to, say, bike helmets have mandated standards). When this has been attempted it tends to result in "box ticking" exercises, and products that meet that standards still end up having issues.
- There are a load of "snake oil" security products. These vendors know very well what security issues their customers face, and promise to fix them. When the experts are saying it's hard to solve, having someone with a shiny product promising to fix your issues is very tempting. The problem is that these products don't deliver the security they promise. The levels of this in enterprise IT are just ridiculous and these vendors are making so much money it's hard to stop.
- Cyber warfare is a strategic opportunity. They keep quiet, but many organisations - the NSA, Chinese government, and more - are extremely good at it. For the NSA, there is an inherent conflict of interest. When they develop hacking techniques, perhaps they should work with tech vendors to fix them and protect people and businesses. However, that would cripple their cyber warfare capability.

Interesting question, hope this helps!